# Unknown provider: $uibModalProvider <- $uibModal <- modalPopDirective

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angular's $uibModal and trying to create popup while page has been loaded. It is not working. I think problem in directive. This is my code:

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .directive('modalPop', ModalDirective)
    .controller('ModalController', ModalController);



function ModalDirective($uibModal) {
    return {
        scope: {},
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'directives/modal/tutorial.html',
        controller: function () {
            return $uibModal.open({
                controller: 'ModalController',
                windowClass: 'outside ' + size,
                animation: true,
                templateUrl: './client/dialogs/' + template + '.html',
                resolve: {
                    dialogParams: function () {
                        return {
                            title: 'title',
                            message: 'message'
                        };
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    };
}

function ModalController($uibModalInstance) {
    $scope.close = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
    };  
}
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

You are not injecting the provider into the directive's controller. Also try explicitly injecting the provider into the directive:

```
ModalDirective.$inject = ['$uibModal'];
function ModalDirective($uibModal) {
    return {
        scope: {},
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'directives/modal/tutorial.html',
        controller: function ($uibModal) {
            return $uibModal.open({
                controller: 'ModalController',
                windowClass: 'outside ' + size,
                animation: true,
                templateUrl: './client/dialogs/' + template + '.html',
                resolve: {
                    dialogParams: function () {
                        return {
                            title: 'title',
                            message: 'message'
                        };
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    };
}
```

If that doesn't work, then **you have not properly included the JS file for Angular UI Bootstrap**. (This is most likely the cause)

Comment: This is my libs in the same sequence:
    - jquery.js
    - jquery-ui.js
    - object-observe.js
    - bootstrap.js
    -  angular.js
    - angular-mocks.js
    - angular-local-storage.js
    - angular-animate.js
    - angular-cookies.js
    - angular-resource.js
    - angular-touch.js
    - angular-sanitize.js
    - angular-permission.js
    - ui-bootstrap.js
    - ui-bootstrap-tpls.js
    - angular-utf8-base64.js
    - ng-websocket.js
    - lodash.js
    - iscroll-probe.js
    - angular-modal-service.min.js